# Cookie set in subfolder isn't set in root - PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie in a subfolder `/admin/setcookies.php` . I'm using this code for doing that:

```
setcookie(
    "username",
    $myusername,
    time()+60*60*24*365,
    "/",
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
    1
);
```

Now when I test if my cookies are set from the root : `/testcookies.php` , I can see they aren't actually set. And when I do the same from `/admin/testcookies.php` , they are in fact set.

What am I doing wrong? The domain name is correct, and the path is set to the root... I don't know what else could be wrong at this point.

Comment: Try to use the domain instead of $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] does output the domain name though. So this shouldn't matter right? Or does it?

Comment: Try to set its domain like `.example.com`. It will accessible from all

Comment: Did try that, didn't work :(

Comment: You set the 6th paramter to `true` ("Indicates that the cookie should only be transmitted over a secure HTTPS connection from the client."). Do you access your page at `/testcookies.php` via HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [6th parameter of `setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) is set to `true`:

> Indicates that the cookie should only be transmitted over a secure HTTPS connection from the client

Your page at `/testcookies.php` must be accessed through HTTPS for the browser to send such a cookie.